# drawableBottom padding is too large when background is set

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a red dot below the text of a button, however the default padding is way too large.
[too large padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqNzS.png)

However, when I remove the background drawable, the padding becomes more reasonable.
[reasonable padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Y9m.png)

Here are the XMLs:

Dot drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="#fff"/>
            <size
                android:height="5dp"
                android:width="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Button:

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/dot"
                android:drawableTint="#FF0000"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                android:text="-"
                app:cornerRadius="0px" />
```

Is there any way to keep reduce the padding further while keeping the background set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a negative padding in your Button. That will fix your problem.

Or you can make a custom button using a linearLayout. In that linearLayout, you can place your views as you want and then treat the linearLayout as a button.

Comment: I resolved this with help from this answer. Notably, I had to set "drawablePadding" to a negative value AND I had to set "paddingBottom" to that same value but positive. Thanks!